# Separable differential equation $x^2 y'' = 2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that $x^2 - x^{-1}$ is a solution of
>   $$x^2 \frac{\text d^2 y}{\text d x^2} = 2y$$

I've tried separating the $x$ and $y$ terms and then integrating, but I could tell it wouldn't work. Any ideas? It's a simple question but I have not attempted them in a while.

Comment: If $x^2 - x^{-1}$ is a solution of $\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = 2y$, then it should satisfy the equation, i.e., $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \left( x^2 - x^{-1} \right) = 2 \left( x^2 - x^{-1} \right)$. But I do not think that this is correct!

Comment: My bad, copied question wrong!

Comment: It is an Euler equation so the general solution is $y = c_1x^2 + c_2\frac{1}{x}$ .

Comment: This equation is not separable. Only first-order equations are separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks to verify the statement in OP. The second derivative of $y: x\mapsto x^2-x^{-1}$ w.r.t. $x$ is $y'': x\mapsto 2 - 2 x^{-3}$. Hence, $$x^2 y''(x) = 2x^2 - 2 x^{-1} = 2 y(x) .$$
The statement in OP is correct.

To solve the differential equation, we proceed the same way as for every [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) by using the trial solution $y=x^m$ or by making the change of variable $t=\ln x$.

Comment: How do you prove this? I've divided 2y(x) by $x^2$ but now I am just left with the second derivative of y and its value in x